# AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'fit_resample'

Tags: python, imblearn

Based on the documentation given on the following link [pipeline and imbalanced](https://machinelearningmastery.com/smote-oversampling-for-imbalanced-classification/)

i have tried to implement  code  on  some dataset, here is code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
from sklearn.pipeline import  Pipeline
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
data =pd.read_csv('aug_train.csv')
data.drop('id',axis=1,inplace=True)
print(data.info())
print(data.select_dtypes(include='object').columns.tolist())
data[data.select_dtypes(include='object').columns.tolist()]=data[data.select_dtypes(include='object').columns.tolist()].apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
print(data.head())
#print(data['Response'].value_counts())
mymodel =GaussianNB()
y =data['Response'].values
print(Counter(y))
X =data.drop('Response',axis=1).values
#X,y =SMOTE().fit_resample(X,y)
#mymodel.fit(X,y)
#print(mymodel.score(X,y))
#print(Counter(y))
over = SMOTE(sampling_strategy=0.1)
under = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy=0.5)
steps = [('o', over), ('u', under)]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=steps)
# transform the dataset
X, y = pipeline.fit_sample(X, y)
```

the main problem in this code is with line :

```
X, y = pipeline.fit_sample(X, y)
```

error  says that  AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'fit_resample' how can i fix this issue? thanks in advance

Comment: Your error says something about 'fit_*re*sample', but your code says fit_sample (fit_resample is in comment)?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'fit_resample' same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tutorial employs [`imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline`](http://glemaitre.github.io/imbalanced-learn/generated/imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html), while your code uses [`sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html) (check `import` expressions).  These appear to be different kinds of `Pipeline`s.